# Show that intersection distributes over the symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been trying to show the following:
$(A \Delta B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \Delta (B \cap C)$

Considering the Venn diagram, the relationship is easily confirmed.

Algebraically, however, the furthest I have gotten, starting from the right side, is:
$((A \Delta B) \cap ((C \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A))) \cap (((A \setminus B) \cup (C \setminus A)) \cap (C \setminus (A \cap B)))$

Analogously, starting from the left side:
$(A \Delta B) \cap (C \cup (B \setminus A)) \cap ((A \setminus B) \cup C) \cap C$

Though both expressions yield the same Venn diagram, I have not figured out how to make a connection between the two expressions.
Did I do unnecessary steps and overshot the easiest path for the solution or am I just not there yet? I am looking forward to your answers!
Thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that $A\Delta B=(A^c\cap B)\cup(B^c\cap A)$. Using this, we can do

\begin{align*}
(A\cap C)\Delta(B\cap C)&=\{(A\cap C)^c\cap (B\cap C)\}\cup\{(B\cap C)^c\cap (A\cap C)\}\\
&=\left[\{(A^c\cup C^c)\cap C\}\cap B\right]\cup\left[\{(B^c\cup C^c)\cap C\}\cap A\right]\\
&=\left[\{(A^c\cap C)\cup (C^c\cap C)\}\cap B\right]\cup\left[\{(B^c\cap C)\cup (C^c\cap C)\}\cap A\right]\\
&=(A^c\cap C\cap B)\cup(B^c\cap C\cap A)\\
&=\{(A^c\cap B)\cup (B^c\cap A)\}\cap C\\
&=(A\Delta B)\cap C
\end{align*}

which proves the required result.

Comment: Ah, you type faster than I do.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take that as a compliment!

Answer (score 5):

$$
(A\Delta B)\cap C=((A\cap B')\cup(A'\cap B))\cap C=(A\cap B'\cap C)\cup(A'\cap B\cap C)
$$
where I'm writing $S'$ for the complement of $S$.
$$
(A\cap C)\Delta(B\cap C)
=((A\cap C)\cap(B\cap C)')\cup((A\cap C)'\cap(B\cap C))
$$
$$
=((A\cap C)\cap(B'\cup C'))\cup((A'\cup C')\cap(B\cap C))
$$
$$=(A\cap C\cap B')\cup(A\cap C\cap C')\cup(A'\cap B\cap C)\cup(B\cap C\cap C')
$$
$$
=(A\cap B'\cap C)\cup(A'\cap B\cap C)
$$